# Find date elements in Dataframe Column that matches specific condition in R

Tags: r, date, dplyr

I am trying to classify instances in a dataframe by `Holidays` or `Normal`.

I have the dates that must be categorized as `Holidays` in a `list/dataframe` object and dates that I want to categorize in another test object.

To be classified as `Holidays`, besides being between the dates that must be categorized in this way, there is a `Condition` in one of the `list/daraframe` columns that must be `1` instead of `0` (i.e. an instance with a date that is actually between `Holidays` dates should be labelled as `Normal` if and only if the corresponding `Condition` is `0`).

**Object containing *database* of days that should be labelled as `Holidays`:**

```
holidays2015 <- list(list("2015-01-01",1,1,1),
                     list("2015-01-06",0,1,1),
                     list("2015-03-19",0,1,1),
                     list("2015-04-02",0,1,1),
                     list("2015-04-03",0,1,1),
                     list("2015-05-01",1,1,1),
                     list("2015-05-02",0,1,1),
                     list("2015-05-15",0,1,1),
                     list("2015-06-04",0,1,1),
                     list("2015-08-15",1,1,0),
                     list("2015-10-12",1,1,1),
                     list("2015-11-09",0,1,1),
                     list("2015-12-08",1,1,0),
                     list("2015-12-24",0,0,1),
                     list("2015-12-25",1,1,0),
                     list("2015-12-31",0,0,1))

holidays2014 <- list(list("2014-01-01",1,1,1),
                     list("2014-01-06",0,1,1),
                     list("2014-04-17",0,1,1),
                     list("2014-04-18",0,1,1),
                     list("2014-05-01",1,1,1),
                     list("2014-05-02",0,1,0),
                     list("2014-05-15",0,1,1),
                     list("2014-06-19",0,1,1),
                     list("2014-08-15",1,1,1),
                     list("2014-11-01",1,1,0),
                     list("2014-11-10",0,1,1),
                     list("2014-12-06",1,1,1),
                     list("2014-12-08",1,1,0),
                     list("2014-12-25",1,1,1))
totalholidays <- list(holidays2015, holidays2014)
dfholidays <- lapply(totalholidays, function(x) data.table::rbindlist(x))
dfholidays <- data.table::rbindlist(dfholidays)
names(dfholidays) <- c("Date", "V2", "V3", "Condition")
```

**Dates that I want to label:**

```
mytestingdates <- as.data.frame(list("Date" = c("2014-01-07", "2014-08-15", 
"2015-06-04", "2015-08-15")))
```

My working solution is a for bucle:

*SlowWay*

```
holidaysvector <- c()
for (ii in 1:nrow(mytestingdates)){
  if (mytestingdates$Date[ii] %in% dfholidays$Date){
    tmp <- which(dfholidays$Date == mytestingdates$Date[ii])
    if (dfholidays$Condition[tmp] == 1) {
      holidaysvector <- c(holidaysvector, "Holidays")
    } else { holidaysvector <- c(holidaysvector, "Normal T.1") }
    } else { holidaysvector <- c(holidaysvector, "Normal T.2") }
}
mytestingdates$forsolution <- holidaysvector
rm(tmp)
```

But I would like a more efficient solutions. I have tried some R options but failed:

*R desired looking alike solution:*

```
mytestingdates$MyRtry <- ifelse(mytestingdates$Date %in% dfholidays$Date, 
ifelse(dfholidays$Condition == 1, "Holiday", "Normal T.1"), "Normal T.2")
```

## Desired solution

```
        Date     MyRtry forsolution
1 2014-01-07 Normal T.2  Normal T.2
2 2014-08-15    Holiday    Holidays
3 2015-06-04    Holiday    Holidays
4 2015-08-15    Holiday  Normal T.1
```

Note that instance no.4 is in the `Holidays` object but its `condition` is 0 so it is labbeled as `Normal` day, this is missed in my R solution.

Any Idea? Any advice in clean code or programming techniques derived from my code will be very much appreaciated.

Comment: Maybe I missed it in your description, but what are the columns "V2" and "V3"?

Comment: Sorry if it was not clear, they are not important, you can disregard them, they are part from the original dataset but not improtant for this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you open to a dplyr solution?

```
library(dplyr)
mytestingdates %>% 
  left_join(dfholidays) %>% 
  mutate(forsolution = ifelse(is.na(Condition), "Normal T.2", ifelse(Condition == 0, "Normal T.1", "Holidays")))
```

In here dfholidays joins mytestingdates. If a date in mytestingdates is not in dfholidays, it merges only NAs for those dates. So then you can check whether Condition is NA, and if so, you set forsolution to "Normal T.2". Subsequently, you check whether Condition == 0, and if so, you let forsolution be "Normal T.1". In the other cases forsolution will be "Holidays".

```
        Date V2 V3 Condition forsolution
1 2014-01-07 NA NA        NA  Normal T.2
2 2014-08-15  1  1         1    Holidays
3 2015-06-04  0  1         1    Holidays
4 2015-08-15  1  1         0  Normal T.1
```

UPDATE: shorter would be:

```
mytestingdates %>% 
  left_join(dfholidays) %>% 
  mutate(forsolution = case_when(is.na(Condition) ~ "Normal T.2", Condition == 0 ~ "Normal T.1",  TRUE ~ "Holidays"))
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it helped me solving the problem and learning other programming thinking lines.

Answer (score 1):

This solution does not distinguish between NormalT1 and NormalT2, but it is quite simple:

```
mytestingdates["classifier"] <- ifelse(mytestingdates$Date %in% dfholidays[dfholidays$Condition==1]$Date,"Holiday", "Normal")

mytestingdates

        Date classifier
1 2014-01-07     Normal
2 2014-08-15    Holiday
3 2015-06-04    Holiday
4 2015-08-15     Normal
```

Comment: I was not sure if you need to distinguish NormalT1 and NormalT2, or whether you did it to make things easier.

Comment: I just added them for clarying the reason to be categorized as "Normal" but no, there is not actual distinction between both. 

Thanks a lot for the code, I knew there would be a ultra-fast way to it but could find it.